# How many times would you have to draw from a deck before there's at least a 90% chance you've drawn the Ace of Spades 5 times (with replacement)

Tags: probability, statistics, problem-solving, binomial-distribution, card-games

Say you have a standard deck of 52 cards with only 1 Ace of Spaces. How many times would you have to "draw and replace" a card to have a 90% chance for the card you drew to have been an Ace of Spades 5 individual times.

I'll try to rephrase it:

Event: You draw a card. If it was the Ace of Spaces, make a mark on your wall. Replace the card and shuffle the deck.

How many times would you need to repeat this event before you have at least a 90% chance of having 5 marks on your wall. (doesn't need to be in a row. Assume that you stop drawing cards once you make the 5th mark on your wall.)

I'm getting into probability and I have no idea how I would approach this problem, would really appreciate if someone could explain to me how this is done!

Comment: Step 1: answer the following: what are the chances of drawing the Ace of Spades exactly twice, given that you drew $n$ times, where $n$ = 3,4, or 5.  Note that here, the $n^{\text{th}}$ card drawn does not need to be the Ace of Spades.  Compute the three separate answers for $n$ = 3,4, or 5.

Comment: @user2661923 Event A is AoS, P = 1/52. Event B is Not, P = 51/52. The chance of drawing an Ace of Spaces twice in a row is (1/52)*(1/52.) The chance of drawing an Ace of Spades at least twice in three tries is... [(1/52)*(1/52)]+1/52? I guess that also assumes that we have to draw the Ace of Spades twice in a row though. I'm not sure how to approach this ^^" I think that the chance of drawing an Ace of Spades at least once in 3 tries is 1-[[1-(1/52)]^3]?

Comment: Good work.  Adopting the terminology that $p = 1/52$, and letting $q = (1 - 52)$, you have that the chance of A-s, A-s, <other card> is $p^2 \times q$.  When $n = 3$, what about (for example) A-s, <other card>, As or <other card>, As, As.  For $n=3$, don't you have to sum all three possibilities?  Are you familiar with Pascal's triangle?  What are the # of ways that you can select $n$ things, taken $k$ at a time.  Can you use this comment to complete Step 1, re $n=3$, $n=4$, and $n=5$?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not familiar with Pascal's Triangle but I have come across "Binomial distribution" while searching on StackOverflow before asking my question. I see that when n = 3, there are 3 possible ways to draw exactly 2 Aces, and to calculate the probability, we'd have to sum the probabilities of each way.  [(1/52)*(1/52)*(51/52)] is one way... Wait, but then all 3 combinations would be equally likely to one another? I've messed up somewhere. I believe to select n things taken k at a time, we'd use nCk =  n!/(k!(n-k)!)  ?

Comment: Yes, and that is enough work.  I'm going to provide an answer.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to do so, thank you!

Comment: Another editing that I think will facilitate computing the minimum value for $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capitalizing on the OP's work, re the comments:

Let $p = (1/52)$ and let $q = (1 - p).$

Given **fixed** $n \in \mathbb{Z^+},$ 
Let $F_n(k) \equiv $ chance of drawing the A-spades **exactly** $k$ times out of $n$ 
where $k \in \{0,1,2, \cdots, n\}.$

Let $G_n(k) \equiv $ chance of drawing the A-spades **at least** $k$ times out of $n$

You want the minimum positive integer $n$ such that $G_n(5) \geq 0.90.$

$$F_n(k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k q^{(n-k)}.$$ 
$$G_n(k) = \sum_{i=k}^n F_n(i)$$

That is, $$G_n(5) = F_n(5) + F_n(6) + \cdots + F_n(n).$$

At this point, for $n$ fixed, you have two choices:

you can compute $G_n(5)$ via the above formula, or you can deduce that

$$G_n(5) = 1 - \left[F_n(0) + F_n(1) + \cdots + F_n(4)\right].$$

This begs the question, is there a **cleaner** formula that can be used
to compute the smallest value of $n$.

I **do not** know of any way to use these formulas other than via a computer.

Note that attempting to find a shortcut through logarithms should fail, because
$G_n(k)$ is equal to the **sum** of some factors, not their product.

**Edit** 
Reaction to "Assume that you stop drawing cards once you make the 5th mark on your wall."

This is a perfectly natural constraint.  Unfortunately, the constraint that you will stop drawing cards adds an unnecessary complication.

The cleanest approach, as represented by my answer, is to assume that for a fixed $n$, you are going to draw $n$ times, and then ask whether you have drawn the Ace of Spades **at least** 5 times.

**Edit-1** 
A case can be made that I have misinterpreted the question that you asked.  The alternative interpretation would be the same as the original, except that you are requiring that the **last** card drawn be the Ace of Spades.

I would compute the answer to the alternative question as

$$F_{(n-1)}(4) \times p.$$

That is $F_{(n-1)}(4)$ represents the probability of drawing   the Ace of spades exactly 4 times out of the first (n-1) drawings.  The $p$ factor represents also drawing the Ace of spades on the $n^{\text{th}}$ drawing.

Then, you would be looking for the smallest value of $n$ where the above formula computes to $0.90$

However, this is **impossible**, because of the final factor in the formula, $p$.

This conclusion may seem counter-intuitive.  For example, if you decide that you are going to draw 10,000 times, the chances of drawing the Ace of Spades at least 5 times out of  10,000 is well over 0.90.  However, the chance of drawing the Ace of Spades exactly 4 times in the first 9,999 times and then drawing the Ace of Spades on the 10,000-th (i.e. the last) drawing is less that (1/52).

In other words, if you are asking how many times do you have to draw so that the combined chances of drawing exactly 4 times out of the first (n-1) draws, and the Ace of Spades on the n-th draw is $\geq$ 90%, the answer is that this is impossible.

**Edit-2** 
Simplification of the determination of $n$ with respect to the primary interpretation of the problem in my answer.

It occurs to me that the algebra can be manipulated to facilitate computing the minimum value of $n$, so that your chances of drawing the Ace of Spades at least 5 times is > 90%.

Suppose we maintain my interpretation of the problem but simultaneously adopt the idea that you **will stop** on the 5th drawing of the Ace of spades.

Then, the chance of your stopping on the $n^{\text{th}}$ drawing is

$$F_{(n-1)}(4)\times p.$$

This means that the chances of stopping **on or before** the $n^{\text{th}}$ drawing is

$$p \times \sum_{k=5}^n F_{(k-1)}(4).$$

Since you want this probability to be $\geq 0.90$, you have to determine the smallest value of $n$, such that

$$\sum_{k=5}^n F_{(k-1)}(4) \geq \frac{0.90}{p}.$$

Based on my understanding, determining the minimum value of $n$, based on the above formula should match perfectly with determining the minimum value of $n$ re

$$G_n(5) \geq 0.90.$$

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for the insights and walking me through the basic steps in comments! I'm certain I cannot yet grasp it, but it allows me a reference to be able to explore the topics of the individual steps further in an attempt to round out my understanding of probability.

If I may ask, what exactly is that form of (n k) in the definition for function F? I understand the Sigma summation and the series following to some extent though. wait, it could just be nCk or nPk?

Comment: I believe the more complicated question is the one I want to be explored, even if I lack the tools right now to understand it. The idea is the "goal" is to reach 5 marks on the wall, and my question is what is the n number of trials would it take before the probability is 0.9 for reaching the goal.

Comment: However, I welcome your initial interpretation for my purposes of learning as well: That it is not required that the last card drawn be the Ace of Spades, (ignoring the constraint that you stop when you have reached 5 Marks on the wall.)

Comment: This is still one of my favourite exchanges I've ever had online - thanks so much for the time and effort you put into indulging a bored engineering student's curiosity!